# Retrieve comments from an implementing facebook comments website

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I can not get Facebook Graph Api to retrieve comments from websites that implements facebook commenting system.

I want to provide sentiment feedback statistics for various websites. I wanted to retrieve comments from few websites which are implementing facebook commenting system, I found graph API method /{object-id}/comments
which should return set of comments from specific object-id (which is an url of article consisting set of facebook comments?). I keep getting json response with ID only or an error with "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review." message. Any feedback on that?

Comment: what´s unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

`/{object-id}/comments` is for objects *on* Facebook - posts, comments, videos, etc. An external website that uses the comments plugin, doesn’t fall under that to begin with.

What you want, is this here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008:

> **Can I get comments for a URL via an API?**
> The comments for every URL can be accessed via the Graph API. Simply make an HTTP GET request to:
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=<YOUR_URL>&access_token=<YOUR_TOKEN>`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response; It does not entirely solve my problem tho, I still get an error "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (OpenGraphObject)". Shold I replace fields with something? Id is url of an ariticle with FB comments and I use user access token generated on Graph API Explorer.

Comment: Hm, looks like this might have been removed recently then. It still works for API versions up to and including 3.2, but with 3.3 it gives that error message, yes.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it.. Anyone else knows if this is the case?